# Recommender system for binary rating

Tags: machine-learning, data-science, recommendation-engine

I'd like to ask if it is possible to build a recommender system on a binary rating (like or doesn't like) system in keras?

EDIT: I am trying to build a recommender system that recommends posts/feeds to users if they like/dislike feeds based on categories/topics (politics, Fashion, Arts/Culture, etc) shown to them.

Comment: Can you add a little more details about the task, the type of data you are working with etc?

Comment: I have put in the edit.

Comment: Show the work you have done, the dataset snapshot, your code .etc for better answers.

Answer (score 1):

You should take a look at factorization machines models. They are very well suited for classification problems with sparse input data.

I found this link after a quick search showing an implementation of factorization machines and DeepFM in Keras (I am not related to the author of this link) : https://6chaoran.wordpress.com/2019/01/03/implement-deepfm-model-in-keras/